# My jquery function is pushing elements to all my arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website, users can click on some text to open up a Modal. This Modal allows users to choose a bunch of toppings to add to their Pizza.

Through Javascript, I add each selected topping to an array and change the text display to match their selected toppings. This more or less works, but the problem is for some reason, whenever they add a topping, it is added to ALL arrays, not just the item it's selected for. Can someone help me find why this is happening?

[image: Page before Alteration]
[image: First Modal]
[image: Second Modal]
[image: Bug]

```
  // Open Toppings Modal
$(document).ready(function() {
var count = -1
var tplist = []
 $(".order").each(function(){
  count += 1
  tplist.push([])
  var listeners = 0
  setModal(count, tplist, listeners)
});

function setModal(count, tplist, listeners) {
  $("#openModal" + count).click(function(){
    console.log("clicked")
    $("#toppingModal" + count).modal()
    if (listeners == 0) {
      listeners += 1
      $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        // TODO: Fix Bug
        // Adding to all javascript lists
        if (this.checked) {
          tplist[count].push($(this).val());
          console.log(tplist)
        }
        else {
          ele = $(this).val();
          pos = $.inArray(ele, tplist[count])

          if ( ~pos ) tplist[count].splice(pos, 1);
        }
        // Change text to list
        if (tplist[count].length > 0) {
          $("#openModal" + count).text(tplist[count])
        }
        else {
          $("#openModal" + count).text("Select Toppings")
        }
      })
    }
});
 };

});
```

Comment: can give  show in jsfiddle if possible

Comment: My Modals are generated dynamically, within my app.py file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suspecting your $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {} is called for every model. Try setting count number somewhere when you click select topping and compare inside $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {} to prevent adding of toppings in all arrays

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I'm not really sure about the solution. Should I change something with the scope in `$("input[type='checkbox']").change` ?

Comment: Thank you. Fixed with `$("#toppingModal" + count + " :checkbox").change(function() {}`

Comment: glad to know it helped you